# Trying to download fedora into my external ssd (samsung T7)

Tags: fedora, system-installation, installer-anaconda

I am trying to download fedora into my external ssd through virtual box however it says I do not have free space, but my SSD has 997gb available . It also gives me an option to reclaim free space however it does not let me do it (screenshots are posted). Could someone help me clarify why is this happening?

[image: drive selection]

[image: reclaim space screen]

[image: device filter of my external ssd]

EDIT: my ssd was in EXFAT so I changed it to NTFS. I followed this tutorial
https://www.samsung.com/au/support/memory-storage/how-do-i-format-my-ssd/

Comment: Try to repartition the external SSD using the host system (that is running VBox) first, before trying to do anything in VBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk has one ExFAT partition that takes all the space on it. The Anaconda installer doesn't support shrinking of ExFAT so you have two options:

1. Use a different tool to resize the partition. AFAICT none of the Linux partitioning tools currently support ExFAT so you need to do this from Windows. After that Anaconda will be able to use the free space to install Fedora.
2. Delete the partition using the *Delete all* button and proceed with the installation. This way you will of course lose all the data on the disk, so use this only if you don't actually use it.

Comment: ok so the external SSD was in ExFAT and I changed it to NTFS. I followed this tutorial, look like it is working https://www.samsung.com/au/support/memory-storage/how-do-i-format-my-ssd/